# Pasar variable de sesión ASP.NET en llamada AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Tengo una variable de sesión donde guardo un `String` y quiero pasarlo como parámetro en la llamada a un método de C#.

Usar un `HiddenField` también serviría para este propósito.

Ejemplo:

```
data: '{loc: "' + Session["auto"].ToString() + '" }',
```

Este es mi código:

```
  function initMap() {
           $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../Services/GoogleMaps.asmx/BindMapMarker") %>',
                    data: '{loc: "' + 'Broadway, Manhattan, Nueva York, Estados Unidos' + '" }',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {}
```

Comment: mi estimado, cuando uno acepta una respuesta: la reputacion personal aumenta tanto de quien pregunta como quien responde, veo que tienes varias preguntas con buenas respuestas (inclusive más de una) para aceptar una respuesta se le da click en el check verde que esta al costado de la respuesta, aqui puedes encontrar la lista de las preguntas que has realizado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6646/efrain-mejias-c?tab=questions. Agradecemos tu colaboración con el sitio. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si puede recomendaria uses el Hidden de asp.net, entonces desde codigo .net asignas el valor

```
Hidden1.Value = Session["auto"].ToString();
```

y desde javascript puedes obtenerlo

```
var auto = $("[id*='Hidden1']").val();

var params = { loc: auto };
```

en `data` del `$.ajax` envias el json

Comment: perfecto quedo asi      data: '{loc: "' + $("[id*='hfLocation']").val() + '" }',

Comment: no necesitas armarlo como string, dfine el json como objeto de javascript he intenta enviarlo, sino funciona usa el JSON.stringify()   https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify